"Option clash for package caption" error message
\documentclass{iaesarticle}

%%required package. add for your convenient, but do not remove the initial
\setlength{\headsep}{0.15in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, float, fancyhdr}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{authblk, graphicx, indentfirst, lastpage, lipsum}
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand{\Authsep}{, }
\renewcommand{\Authand}{, }
\renewcommand{\Authands}{, }
\setlength{\affilsep}{0cm}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{8}{10}\mdseries}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]\hfill}
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\bfseries#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[font=normalsize=]{subfig, caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}{\thesection}{1.7em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{.95em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{.2em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0.7cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}






%%author
\author[1]{\bfseries xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

%%author's affiliation
\affil[1]{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
%%title and shortitle (for footer)
\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
%%starting
\begin{document}

\end{document}


Can you add a link to where we can get the class from? You are loading the caption package multiple times with different options. Try to only load it once. You are also loading other packages more than once. Maybe take this opportunity and clean up your preamble.

What's the reason for trying to load caption twice? For that matter, why do you try to load graphicx twice?

I'm rather sure you don't need epstopdf, you can drop it from your preamble as well. Also note that calls to \author usually don't include formatting instructions but only the name (plus possible footnotes in \thanks), it is the job of the class to use that data and typeset it in a nice way.

you are loading caption twice with different options once \usepackage[font=normalsize=]{subfig, caption} (with two = ???) and once \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}  so an option clash error is quite expected. You should remove every package load that references an already loaded package (you show several)

It seems you are using a journal class (with unclear license). Usually you should primary use such classes for submissions to the corresponding journal. But in this case you should not change basic formatting like the formatting of sections, page header and footer etc. Strange enough: The journal template also does such changes with the same mistakes you've shown. Therefore you should report this issue to the maintainer/editor. Because if you have to use this template, it should also be error-free.
